# how to wait function call to finish before to return?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I tried to use async/await then I put await on a function call but even it still not finished it already execute the next line.

```
async function listFreeAccounts() {
    let rnds = [];
    await gun.get('freeAccounts').map().once((v, k) => {
        // this will be called many times defending on the number of values exists.
        // then push it on the array.
        rnds.push(k);
    });

    // Premature returns here, making the rnds values empty.
    return rnds;
};
```

How I can make to wait to push all the values in `rnds` before returning it?

Thanks.

**Edit**

I am using [gundb](https://github.com/amark/gun) that's the `gun.get(...` code.

Comment: What does `once` return?

Comment: that is a key value pair, if it found 10 items then it will call the callback 10 times

Comment: `await` on a non-promise will return immediately, so if the library function doesn't return a promise, then you can't do it this way.

Comment: You can only await a function that returns a promise. Does gun.get('freeAccounts').map().once() return a promise? If not, you'll need to wrap it in a function that does return a promise.

Comment: ohh, I will try it and get back later